# shell/Python script to utilize memory 100% for 20 mins

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell

Is there any  python/Shell  script to make memory 100% usage for 20 minutes.

Memory size is very big 4TB.

Operating System Linux.
Python version 2.7

Comment: Create a big numpy array that uses all ram?

Comment: anything is fine but it must use all the memory its for testing

Comment: @syntonym Well, _not_ all ram, most of the ram. The Linux kernel resides in ram and user processes cannot access this part of memory. Other user processes' ram pages cannot be accessed arbitrarily by other processes too.

Comment: any tools available to make memory 100% usage

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
import time
l = []
t = time.time()
while True:
  try:
    l.append('string')  # pack your memory
  except MemoryError:
    break
while (time.time()-t) < 20*60:  # repeat for 20 minutes.
  l[0] = 'string'
```

Comment: if you want high CPU usage as well. If you don't care about CPU, you can simply `time.sleep()` for the remaining time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any python/Shell script to make memory 100% usage for 20 minutes.

To be technical, we need to be precise. 100% usage of the whole memory by a single process isn't technically possible. Your memory is shared with other processes. The fact that the kernel is in-memory software debunks the whole idea.

Plus, a process might start another process, say you run Python from the shell, now you have two processes (the shell and Python) each having their own memory areas.

If you mean by that a process that can consume most of ram space, then yes that's not impossible.